# C# Winforms form losing focus when focusing on child control ... sometimes

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, focus, compact-framework

I am developing a windows mobile 6.5 app and have issues with my form losing focus when focusing on a child control of a UserControl added to the form... sometimes.

In my app I navigate between screens by adding and removing user controls to the main form controls collection.

```
IView nextView = (IView)Activator.CreateInstance(map.View);

this.Controls.Remove((UserControl)this.currentView);

this.currentView = nextView;

this.Controls.Add((UserControl)this.currentView);
```

My basic flow for navigation between screens is thus:

**First add of UserControl A**

1. Initialize UserControl A
2. Add UserControl A to Form.Controls
3. Focus on grid on A

**Navigate to UserControl B**

1. Initialize UserControl B
2. Remove UserControl A from Form.Controls
3. Add UserControl B to Form.Controls

**Navigate back to UserControl A**

1. Initialize UserControl A
2. Remove UserControl B from Form.Controls
3. Add UserControl A to Form.Controls
4. Focus on grid on A

All this works fine and on the first add of UserControl A the form is focused and the child control has focus as well.

But when I navigate back to UserControl A from UserControl B the form loses focus, but only if I try to focus on the child control in the last step. In my app this has the consequence that I cannot navigate in the grid using the phone hardware buttons.

Any idea on why the main form loses focus?

Comment: Why remove/add the this.currentView?

Comment: Just a hunch, but perhaps try adding the new view before removing the old one such that there is always a focusable control on the form.

Comment: You can connect to the application with Remote SPY which is a part of Visual Studio 2008 Remote tools. This tool helps you to catch the WM_SETFOCUS and WM_KILLFOCUS messages. Maybe it helps to better understand the situation. And show us the Focus code, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that when I navigated back to UserControl A, which I do by triggering a navigation event in the middle of a method, the code in UserControl B continued to execute thereby preventing focusing on UserControl A.

I had hoped that when I removed UserControl B from Form.Controls (and then disposing it) the rest of the method wouldn't be executed, kind of like Response.Redirect does for web.

I solved the problem by adding a return; statement after triggering the OnNavigation event in UserControl B.